# Custom Actions from Api.ai with Google Assistant on PI

Tags: google-api, raspberry-pi, action, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Hey there I would like to use the Google Assistant SDK on PI. So Everything with google works on PI, but I have no clue how to invoke Custom Actions I created with api.ai . IFTTT works, but I would like to use Api.AI as google mentioned this may be possible with the Google Assistant SDK and api.ai

Thanks!

Comment: In the end I solved the Problem by myself:
1. Create the Api.Ai Actions, then activate Actions on Google Integration.
2. Create the Project on the Google Page
3. Use the Json of the recently created Project for PI Setup
4. Activate "Test" on Api.Ai Google Actions Integration
5. Profit!

Comment: Thanks. I was scratching my head over how to test my custom action on RPi. The only thing I'd add is - once you run the google assistant on RPi, don't forget that you need to say "talk to my test app" before you can test your action.